# ReLU() returns an error but Activation('relu') works fine on TensorFlow Functional API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Per the documentation `Activation('relu')` and `ReLU()` should yield similar results except for the additional arguments in `ReLU()`.

However,

```
X = Activation('relu')(X)
```

works fine. but

```
X=ReLU()(X)
```

gives the following error:

```
NameError: name 'ReLU' is not defined
```

Why is this? Is `ReLU()` not supposed to be used with the functional API?

Comment: You need to import `ReLU` class first: `from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU`

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand activation functions and ReLU.

They will not always return the same value but RelU is Rectified Linear Unit activation function but activation ReLU is target layer activation Fn.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

layer = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
output = layer([-3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 2.0])
print(output.numpy())
print( "================" )

print( tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(tf.constant([-3.0, -1.0, 0.0, 2.0], shape=( 4, 1 )).numpy()) )
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
F:\temp\Python>python test_tf_ReLU.py
2022-05-10 12:38:02.190099: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-05-10 12:38:02.770833: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4634 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
[0. 0. 0. 2.]
================
(None, 4, 1)
[[[0.       ]
  [0.       ]
  [0.       ]
  [2.0980666]]]

F:\temp\Python>
```